# SQL Server: Date Format (MON DD, YYYY)

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008. I want to show the right abbreviation of September which is **Sept** not **Sep** in the report.

This is my code:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), SO.CREATED, 107) AS CREATED
```

The result is: `Sep 5, 2016`

But the result should be: `Sept 5, 2016`

How would I correct my formatting?

Comment: You say the _right_ abbreviation, do you mean that all month names should be 4 characters in length?

Comment: @ChrisPickford: good luck with May ! :-)

Comment: Just the September.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should probably do the trick for you:

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),SO.CREATED,107),'Sep','Sept') AS CREATED;
```

Comment: And how would this apply to other months?

Comment: To apply to other months you should probably read what the `REPLACE` function actually does. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) is the link!

Answer (score 0):

Try *[REPLACE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx)* command, as you need only for *Sept month* (as per my understanding of the question)!

```
SELECT (REPLACE (CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), SO.CREATED, 107) ), 'Sep', 'Sept') AS CREATED
```

Hope this works!